# How do I handle server side rendering error in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement server side rendering in Nextjs using sanity studio to fetch the posts.

```
interface Props {
  posts: [Post];
}

export default function Home({ posts }: Props){
  
  return (
    <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto">
      <Head>
        <title>APP</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Header />
     
      <div>
        {posts?.map((post) => (
          <Link key={post._id} href={`/post/${post.slug.current}`}>
            <div>
              <img src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()!} alt="" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p>{post.title}</p>
                <p>
                  {post.description} by {post.author.name}
                </p>
              </div>
              <img src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()!} alt="" />
            </div>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};



export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post"]{
    _id,
    title,
    author ->{
      name,
      image
    },
    description,
    mainImage,
    slug
  }`
  const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
  return { props: { post } }
  
};
```

When fetching the post I get error saying post is undefined. Please any help  will be appreciated, so i would know what I'm doing wrongly or missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting a `posts` property so you should pass:

```
const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query);
return { props: { posts } }
```